# How to iterate and print nested HashMap with Integer as value?

Tags: java, hashmap, integer, println, getvalue

I want to print a nested HashMap which is :

```
HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Character,Integer>> map;
```

I searched a lot but I can't find a way to print the Integer because when I use getValues() on it, it tells me : "cannot find symbol". (Because it's an Integer value)

This is what I tried to do :

```
public void print(){
   for(Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Character,Integer>> t :this.map.entrySet()){
     Integer key = t.getKey();
     for (Map.Entry<Character,Integer> e : this.map.getValue().entrySet())
       System.out.println("OuterKey:" + key + " InnerKey: " + e.getKey()+ " VALUE:" +e.getValue());
   }
}
```

I can't use getValue() in my second for, so what else can I use ?

Thanks in advance !
Have a nice day.
Chris.

Answer (score 6):

`getValue()` is a method of `Map.Entry`, not `Map`.

You should use `t.getValue().entrySet()` instead of `this.map.getValue().entrySet()` in the second loop.

That would give you the inner Map.

```
public void print(){
   for(Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Character,Integer>> t :this.map.entrySet()){
     Integer key = t.getKey();
     for (Map.Entry<Character,Integer> e : t.getValue().entrySet())
       System.out.println("OuterKey:" + key + " InnerKey: " + e.getKey()+ " VALUE:" +e.getValue());
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eran it works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to print the whole thing:

```
System.out.println(map.toString());
```

Yep, thats it; toString() returns a string ... that contains all the content of your Map; including its inner Map!

If you want to do that yourself, then you can use **two** loops:

```
for(Map.Entry<Integer, HashMap<Character,Integer>> innerMap : map.entrySet()) {
  for (Map.Entry<Character, Integer> aMap : innerMap.entrySet) {
    ... now you can call aMap.getKey() and .getValue()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Character,Integer>> map = new HashMap<Integer,HashMap<Character,Integer>>();
        HashMap<Character,Integer> map1 = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        map1.put('1', 11);
        HashMap<Character,Integer> map2 = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
        map2.put('2', 22);
        map.put(111, map1);
        map.put(222, map2);

        for (Integer temp : map.keySet()) {
            for (Character c : map.get(temp).keySet()) {
                System.out.println("key--" + c + "--value--" + map.get(temp).get(c));
            }
        }
    }
```

Hope it works.